# excel error checking flags cell as number formatted as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in an excel sheet that has the triangular error flag which displays "the number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe". That is not the case, all the characters are numeric and the cell format is number. Is there another condition under which this will happen?

I ask because it is creating a problem when accessing the excel file as a database table with another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the warning icon and choose "Convert to Number". This issue happened because the values were originally supplied when the cells were once formatted as text.

Comment: I know that will convert to number, I want to know WHY excel thinks that cell is text.

Comment: It's not a matter of why it thinks that way, it's common sense to warn you when values are formatted as numbers when they were originally formatted as text. If the original values were placed in a number formatted cell to begin with, switching formats does not produce this warning.

Comment: You are right, I tried formatting a cell as text then entered the number & got the error. I wonder why changing the format back to number doesn't get rid of the error.

Comment: Id does not get rid of the warning to prevent unintended consequences. Suppose out of thousands of rows, there was a non-numeric value. It is a way to confirm if the new number format is in fact valid. Going the direction from number format to text format is not worth a warning message since it does not involve numeric calculations.

Comment: Do you know if there is way to change an existing cell that is numeric to one that excel thinks is numeric formatted as text?
(without adding an apostrophe etc)
In effect, I WANT the error flag to occur.

Comment: I should add: using VBA

Answer (score 0):

Run Data ► Text to Columns ► Fixed Width ► Finish and you can convert an entire column of imported pseudo-numbers from text that look like number to actual numbers.